# jQuery is loading only from master page layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using MVC framework. jQuery is loaded in the layout page but when I try to run script on pages that are using the layout page, the script is not running and gives this error:
**Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**
I am running the following script to debug

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (jQuery) {
        // jQuery is loaded
          alert("Yeah!");
          alert($().jquery);
        } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
          alert("Doesn't Work");
        }
    });
```

If I put this script it will run and if I put it in a page that uses the layout page it will not run.
I tried to load jQuery locally and from CDN and both method has the same problem.

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code on how your loading your jQuery js file

Comment: ' <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <script src="~/datatable/DataTables-1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I found a tip there about using @section Scripts. I used it and the problem is solved

Comment: Glad to help. Next time make sure it is not a question that is asked here in stack overflow . Helps to avoid redundancy. Also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question.